# Push all git repos sequentially, in vscode multiroot workspace

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-git

I use a multiroot workspace in vscode. In the source control sidebar, I can commit changes and push to origin (for each repo).

But often I have to push multiple repos. Although I can click the "Sync Changes" button for each repo:

- I can't push too many at once (our git server doesn't work well under load)
- and each push takes some time (~20s)

So doing this for a few dozen projects is a chore.

Is there a "push all repos" feature, which pushes sequentially?

Comment: @starball Because if I push multiple repos at once then the server crashes, don't know why, and it's not in my control - whereas if I push one at a time it works. But I must sit there for 20 minutes doing it manually. :-/ I hoped there was a "push all" feature but can't find one (which was surprising because the multiroot feature is otherwise quite smart).

Comment: Just do a for loop on the command line. I'm assuming you're using a unix machine right (Mac, Linux)? If you're using Windows I can't really help you as I don't know powershell

Comment: @slebetman most windows users with Git will have gotten it from Git for Windows, which comes with Git Bash (Bash with some UNIX commands).

Comment: @slebetman Yes I've a bash script which does that for me. I hoped there's a native vscode feature but looks like there isn't.